# error en una sentencia de PHP - WARNING

Tags: php, sql

Recibo el siguiente error:

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /database.class.php on line 96
```

y la linea es la siguiente:

```
public function query($query)
{
    $this->result = $this->mysqli->query($query); // Esta es la linea   
    return $this->result;
}
```

Arriba tengo esta linea que conecta a la base de datos:

```
class ConnectMe
{
    public function __construct($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name) 
    {
        $this->db_server = $db_server;  
        $this->db_username = $db_username;
        $this->db_password = $db_password;
        $this->db_name = $db_name;

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->db_server, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);

        if($this->mysqli->connect_error)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->mysqli->query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
        $this->mysqli->query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
        $this->mysqli->query('SET character_set_results=utf8'); 
    }
```

Podrian ver en que esta mi error ?

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

intenta asi:

```
$query = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)
if($query->execute()){
   return $consulta->get_result();
}
```

Comment: Copie el codigo pero no me funciono.

Comment: Bryo, su respuesta apareció en la lista de publicaciones de baja calidad. Para evitar esto, agregue una explicación de qué hace este código y cómo ayuda al OP *original poster* o usuario que creó la pregunta.